# NestJS @mongoosejs/double Property Declaration

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, double

I am currently working on a code first NestJS/Graphql API.

I am running into a common issue where the API will save a number as an Int32 if the number contains no decimals. This is not an acceptable solution as it will cause issues with Atlas App Sync if the type for the field on the document is not a double.

I am executing the following mutation on each request:

```
mutation {
    createTask(createTaskInput: {
        _partition: "example",
        asset_id: "6298fd63e2f769eb3d33f9db",
        inspection_id: "6377ca75665d8b000013e5e0",
        name: "Test Task",
        comment: "abc123"
        estimated_quantity: 25.0
        total_quantity: 50.75
    }) {
        _id
        _partition
        asset_id
        inspection_id
        name
        comment
        estimated_quantity
        total_quantity
    }
}
```

I am trying a couple different property declarations within the class. Both of the below property declarations is using the @mongoosejs/double package.

The first attempted declaration looks like:

```
@Prop()
@Field(() => Float)
estimated_quantity: Double;
```

With this declaration, the following error is thrown and the project will not build:
*Error: Cannot determine a type for the "Task.estimated_quantity" field (union/intersection/ambiguous type was used). Make sure your property is decorated with a "@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })" decorator.*

If I update the declaration to allow the project to build by using the following code snippit:

```
@Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.Number })
@Field(() => Float)
estimated_quantity: Double;
```

The project will build but will still save the input as an Int32.

I have also tried importing the double package using the following:

```
const Double = require("@mongoosejs/double");
```

However, I am unable to utilize this due to the following error:
*Double' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Double*

Any suggestions to get this working would be greatly appreciated. The create-dto must save the number value as a double regardless of provided input.

Comment: @rickhg12hs this is already using the mongoose-double mongoose plugin. The question is getting it to work without the above errors. I will edit the post to specify that.